# Call functions that have an attribute/characteristic

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've run into a problem while designing an abstract base class for something I'm building.

My class defines an `Executor` which I want to create children of and add more functionality to.

On paper I want my Executor to have 2 steps of operation:

1. Before-Execute Stage
2. Execute Stage

The `run` function runs these steps in order.

With regards to the `Before-Execute` stage, this can consist of calling multiple functions on the object -> some abstract functions and some other additional functions in derived classes.

I've been trying to figure out a way to be able to have functions called in the `Before-Execute` stage without having to redefine the `before_execute` function in each derived class.

The way I've achieved this (which I don't really like) is by defining a member list `before_execute_functions` which contains the names of all the functions I want called in the `Before-Execute` stage.

The `before_execute` function traverses the list and calls each function sequentially. In derived classes, I can add the names of any other functions I want called in the `Before-Execute` stage to the list.

The code looks like this:

```
class Executor:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        self.before_execute_functions = ['get_script', 'get_input']

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_script(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_input(self):
        pass

    def before_execute(self):
        #call each function in the list
        for f in self.before_execute_functions:
            if not getattr(self, f)():
                return False
        return True

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def execute(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
          self.before_execute()
          self.execute()
```

Which I can use like:

```
class MyExecutor(Executor):

    def __init__(self):
        Executor.__init__(self)
        self.before_execute_functions.append('my_other_function')

    def get_script(self):
        #do stuff
        pass

    def get_input(self):
        #do stuff
        pass

    #An additional function I want called 
    #during the Before-Execute stage
    def my_other_function():
        #do stuff
        pass

    def execute(self):
       #do stuff
        pass
```

But I don't like the solution I've come up with and I'm wondering if there is any way to add an attribute or tag to a function. So then in my `before_execute` function I could just call all the functions with the eg. `before` attribute/tag. This would save me having to manage a member list.

Is anything like this possible? Or can anyone think of a better way to achieve this? And also, please don't hesitate tell me if I'm being an idiot! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Aside: you've tagged this with python2.7, but AFAIK, metaclasses only work on new-style classes (which you don't have since you haven't derived `Executor` from `object`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define `before_execute` more explicitly:

```
class Executor(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def before_execute(self):
        #call each function in the list
        return self.get_script() and self.get_input()
```

Now if the user wants to add more actions, they can override `before_execute` calling the superclass's method as necessary:

```
class MyExecutor(Executor):
    def before_execute(self):
        result = super(MyExecutor, self).before_execute()
        return result and self.my_other_function()
```

The only thing you lose with this approach is the ability to re-order the execution of the various functions in the chain.  What you *gain* is the ability for the various functions to have different signatures (since you're calling them explicitly).  Additionally, this paradigm seems to be more typical/expected which would lead to greater readability (IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

run_before = []

def append_to_before_fns(func):
   global run_before
   run_before.append(func)

@append_to_before_fns
def hello():
    print 'hello '

@append_to_before_fns
def world():
    print 'world'

def run():
    global run_before
    for f in run_before:
        f()


if __name__=='__main__':

    run()
```

would output

```
hello
world
```

Declare the decorator in your Executor class, then you can call it in your children classes.